# using captcha with javascript focus change

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, recaptcha

I have a form that is a validation field, there is a rand() server variable that displays on the page, the user has to type that code in to complete a successful validation. When the user changes focus from this field, a script opens a php file that checks the validity of the code the user has entered with the server code. If the code matches, the user is shown a button to submit the form, if the code is entered incorrectly, the user gets an error message.

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#usercode").blur(function()
{
    //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Checking...').fadeIn("slow");
    //check the username exists or not from ajax
    $.post("check.php",{ usercode:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
    {
      if(data=='no') //if username not avaiable
      { 
        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
        {//alert(data);
          //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
          $(this).html('Your code was incorrect').addClass('messageboxerror') .fadeTo(900,1);
        });     
      }
      else
      {
        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
        {// alert(data);
          //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
          $(this).html('<input type="submit" value="Post Your Story"/>').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1);    
        });
      }

    });

});
});
</script>
```

/////this is what check.php looks like\\\\

```
<?
session_start();

$sescode= $_SESSION['code'];
$usercode = $_POST['user_name'];

if ($sescode==$usercode) {
// What happens when valid
echo("yes");
} else {
// what happens when invalid
 echo "no";
 }
?>
```

finally there is the input field

```
<input type="text" id="usercode" name="usercode" />
```

I need a way to adapt this script to work with the captcha validation tool. I was spammed like crazy yesterday, and I would like a way to adapt this script to use the captcha utility, I would like the validation script to run after the focus is changed from the captcha object. Thanks!

edit: an example of said form can be viewed here: http://www.mybadhookups.com/ist331.php

Comment: Hopefully you're still doing server-side validation. because hiding a submit button on the client-side is a trivial bump in the road and easily bypassed.

Comment: absolutely, I am using spry validation as well.

Comment: Are you using any javascript libraries? jQuery for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I answered my own question by looking at your code.

Look at Keith Woods jQuery plugin for captcha here: http://keith-wood.name/realPerson.html

He even has the server side code on the tab for that :)

Comment: Awesome, but isn't that still susceptible to ocr?

Comment: Perhaps a bit, but not as much as what you had previously at least.